# Binding controls to LINQ queries - cannot find field

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, binding

I have several controls that I am trying to bind to LINQ queries but am getting the following error:

> $exception {"DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'Key'."} System.Exception
>   {System.Web.HttpException}

I'm binding it the following way:

```
    myDropDownList.DataSource = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(
                        r => ((string) r["ColumnName"]) == "ColumnIWant").ToList()
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Key";
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
```

I have tried this both with and without the .ToList(), as suggested in other answers but with no effect.

`"myDataTable"` has both columns `"Key"` and `"Value"`. It was my understanding you could bind this way, but I seem to be missing a step in specifying the property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [.CopyToDataTable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) works for what I'm trying to do, but I'd still prefer to know how to bind the data directly to the EnumerableRows collection if that's possible.

Here is what I did:

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(
                        r => ((string) r["ColumnName"]) == "ColumnIWant").CopyToDataTable();
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Key";
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
```

Comment: You should mark an answer as correct. Even if it's yours or someone else's.

Comment: You can't mark your own answer correct for 2 days. Your solution also does not work.

Comment: Oh now I see... It's tested BTW but lets just leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (as it has worked to me this way with GridView and DropDownList controls), is that you specify this `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties in the design file (aspx) like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                  DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This way, you can still apply the `ToList()` function to the DataTable and it will work (tested).

If if doesn't, maybe you need to set up one break-point after filling up your `myDataTable` and another one after the LINQ query, to check if the "Key" and "Value" columns are still there.

Answer (score 0):

If it defenitely contains values for `key` and `Value` in the data table then i suggest you to use like the following :

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(
                    r => (r.Field<string>("ColumnName")) == "ColumnIWant").ToList<DataRow>();
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Key";
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
```

I had changed `ToList()` to `.ToList<DataRow>();` so that the datasourse can find the `key` and `value` as same as from a datatable, and change the comparison like this: `r.Field<string>("ColumnName")`

Comment: How is this any different?

Comment: oh you don't see any difference in this? have you tried? see my updates

Comment: Do they not both do the same thing? Is r["ColumnName"] not equivalent to  r.Field<string>("ColumnName")? And .ToList<DataRow>() is just a redundant way of calling .ToList() on the Row collection. Yes I did try it, same error.